# BindResult hasErrors method not showing

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, gradle

I'm doing a case study on Spring MVC and for some reason I'm unable to call the .hasErrors method within my BindResult class :

```
@PostMapping("/jedi")
public String createJedi(@Valid @ModelAttribute Jedi jedi, BindResult bindResult) {

    if (bindResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "new-jedi";
    }

    jediRepository.addJedi(jedi);
    return "redirect:jedi";
}
```

Not sure if this is a version incompatibility problem, or something's missing in my code.

I'm following a tutorial online and the guy explaining it didn't do anything different from me, so I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: There is no `BindResult` in Spring, you need to use `BindingResult`. `BindResult` is propably from a different framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public String createJedi( @ModelAttribute("yourModelName") @Valid Jedi jedi, 
 BindingResult bindingResult) {

   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "new-jedi";
    }

   jediRepository.addJedi(jedi);
   return "redirect:jedi";
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps